# Exiting Shoes app breaks my loop! How can I prevent this?

Tags: ruby, loops, shoes

I have a command_line (shell) `loop` that waits for the user to input characters. Depending on what the user types, different things will happen but the loop will always continue until a user types "quit".  For only one command, I wish to open a shoes app. Opening works fine but when I close it, the loop breaks and the process ends. I don't want the process to end. It looks something like this...

```
def mainLoop()
  loop do
    print "Input word: "
    word = gets.chomp.split(' ')
    if word.length == 0
      launchShoesApp(word[0])
    end

    ...

  end
end

def create_gui(graph)
  Shoes.app { button "Push me" }
end
```

When the Shoes.app GUI is closed, the entire process closes. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I tried returning from the app to no avail... right now I'm trying spawning the app in a thread and joining with the main thread once its completed.

Comment: Threads ended up working (partially)! I can now return to the loop but now I can only open the shoes app once. Upon running the same command in the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend to separate out the command line ruby script code and the Shoes script code in different files
For example:

```
#command-line.rb
def mainLoop()
 loop do
  print "Input word: "
  word = gets.chomp.split(' ')
  if word.length == 0
   #launchShoesApp(word[0])
   Process.spawn("ruby shoes-gui.rb") 
   # this will spawn up a process (opening your shoes app) without blocking this ruby script.
  end
 end  
end
```

and,

```
#shoes-gui.rb
require 'green_shoes'
Shoes.app { button "Push me" }
```

Make sure that both the files are in same folder. Also make sure that u have installed 'green_shoes' gem. If at all you are not OK with green_shoes and want to use the red shoes only, the you can change the system command

```
from:
'ruby shoes-gui.rb'
to:
'yourpath/to/shoes shoes-gui.rb'
```

Generally you will find shoes executable at home/username/.shoes/federales/shoes if you are using linux and somewhere in C drive if on windows.

This should most probably work (I tested it on my machine). Hope it helps :)